# send from tableview didselect to seque to send other controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, swift3

I have table get some things from json
whin I select the row indexof row i want to open other control 
and other control get some varbiles for first one
imake the code
but in the code try to send from tableview to seque but in seque nothing happen what wrong in the code
I want to get url fro table

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:
    IndexPath)
{

  // let selectedEpisode = self.episodes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "videoplay", sender: indexPath);

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.alpha = 0
    let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -250, 20, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = transform
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        cell.alpha = 1
    }
}
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "videoplay" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
           let selectedEpisode = self.episodes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
           let yosrihh = selectedEpisode.url! as URL
           let destination = segue.destination as! videoPlayViewController

            destination.urll = yosrihh
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in Swift 3 `prepareForSegue(:sender:)` is changed to `prepare(for:sender:)`, so just change the method like this then all set to go.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate :)